# SASS variables not rendering correct results in VueJS app

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, vuejs2

I have 2 SASS var colors:

```
$red: '#F06292';
$lightPurple: '#8F6894';
```

Code:

```
<style lang="scss">
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata|Oswald');

$red: '#F06292';
$lightPurple: '#8F6894';

#app {
  font-family: 'Inconsolata', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

html, body {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  color: #B987C0;
}

#nav {
  padding: 30px;
  a {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: $lightPurple;  // <--
    &.router-link-exact-active {
      color: $red;  // <--
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

Markup:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="nav">
      <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
      <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
    </div>
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>
```

Result:

[image]

And if I just change `$red` back to `red`:

```
&.router-link-exact-active {
  color: red;
}
```

[image]

In the browser it gave this style to my links instead: `color: -webkit-link;`

[image]

The rest of my sass is working, like indentation, thought I haven't tried mixins yet. Any thoughts here?

Comment: You forgot to add the markup.

Comment: Sorry, just added! @AndreiGheorghiu

Comment: What do the element styles look like in your browser console?

Comment: @Phil added! Yeah it gave this strange style: `color: -webkit-link;`

Comment: If you hover that little yellow triangle, what does it say?

Comment: @Phil `invalid property value`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$red: '#F06292';
$lightPurple: '#8F6894';
```

should be

```
$red: #F06292;
$lightPurple: #8F6894;
```